# Hide button if mailto: is empty

Tags: javascript, php, forms, email, html-email

I have a list of users and if they have an email they can click on a button to send an email. The thing is that I need to hide the EMAIL button if the user doesn't have a email.

Here is what i have:

```
<form action='/' method='get'>
<a href='mailto:<?=$user['email']?>'><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"><span>Email</span></button></a>
</form>
```

This is what i tryed but didn't work:

```
<a href='mailto:<?=$user['email']?>'><button id="sendmail" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" onload="hideButton()"><span>Email</span></button></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    function hideButton(){
        if(email === "mailto:"){
            $("#sendmail").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#sendmail").hide();
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I don't know how to solve it. I google this but most of the answers gives me an Error 500 when I upload to the website

Comment: *<?=$user['email']?>* what syntax is this? Are you using a PHP template engine for HTML rendering?

Comment: @Toxnyc - `<?= ... ?>` is short syntax for `<?php echo ... ;?>`

Comment: @waterloomatt that looks very clean, do you have the link to the doc?

Comment: @Toxnyc - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php#language.basic-syntax.phptags. Notice the difference between _short echo tag_ (this) and _short open tag_, which should be avoided and may be removed entirely in a future version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it directly in PHP just by wrapping it an *if* statement.

```
<?php

if (isset($user['email']) && trim($user['email']) !== '') {
    echo '<a href="mailto:' . $user['email'] . '">Send email</a>';
}
```

Comment: And I should also point out that if your email link is just a link, it doesn't need to be wrapped in a form. Forms are only used to submit form inputs such as text boxes, radio buttons etc. I see that you're wrapping a button within the link but this is kind of redundant. Just use the link by itself.

Comment: Turn on error, reporting and then edit your _question_ with the appropriate details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/296555